# Running into issue with libcurl4 on Ubuntu18.04LTS (bionic) some third party packages uses libcurl3 and hence not works

Tags: 18.04

My PC was crashed last night and when I reinstall Ubuntu18.04LTS, while installing my dev packages curl, node, mongodb etc... I have installed curl and when I am going to install mongodb-org* it depends on libcurl3 and can't install. When you isntall  libcurl3 with openssl then CURL libcurl4 is going to be removed.